# QSettings IniFormat File gets empty after restart

Tags: qt, restart, ini, qsettings

I use QSettings to save and load parameters to/from an ini file using Linux:

write:

```
QSettings settings("setup.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.beginGroup("Setup_Parameter");
settings.setValue("Parameter1",parameter1_value);
settings.sync();
settings.endGroup();
```

read:

```
QSettings settings("setup.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.beginGroup("Setup_Parameter");
parameter1_value = settings.value("Parameter1","0").toInt();
settings.endGroup();
```

The setup.ini works fine, while the system is on.
If i reboot my system by switching power off and on again, the setup.ini file gets  completely empty sometimes. I would say in 3 out of 5 trys.

I already tryed saving the file in application and root/Settings path.
As well as copying the file after writing it, but then also the copy is empty after power off and on.

Why does the setup.ini File looses its content? It needs to keep the parameters while restart.

Comment: Could you explicitly state a question please?

Comment: I need the setup.ini to keep its content. Why is the setup.ini sometimes empty, after power off and on?

Comment: Try to rename a file, maybe something deleting it? There's no other explanations of this happens 3 of 5 times. And there's no need to settings.sync(), especially before settings.endGroup(), according QSettings [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#sync), maybe error is here?

Comment: What should i rename? the setup.ini? i did sync(), because i used to do a backup copy right after the write. But like i wrote, also this backup file (cp setup.ini setup.bak) got empty. Btw: the file doesnt get deleted, its still there, but empty.

Comment: Ok, first, move sync() after endGroup(). I think it can help. I proposed renaming just to prevent outside interference.

Comment: This doesn't help. It feels like the ini file isn't totally saved by this write function. Like it is only saved in a buffer. And because i do not do a software shutdown or reboot, but switching off the power at once, this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sync() was required after the write function:

```
QSettings settings("setup.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.beginGroup("Setup_Parameter");
settings.setValue("Parameter1",parameter1_value);
settings.endGroup();
settings.sync();
sync();
```

Comment: where is the `sync()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem.  My QSettings file gets wiped out sometimes after a power reset.  The file remains, but it is zero bytes in size.  The QT application is running on Debian Squeeze on an ARM processor. The filesystem, OS, and application are all located on a 4G SD Card.

I've modified the application to call the sync function after any change to the Settings file. But we had a power reset last night and one of the units (we have about 60 running) lost its settings.  We're running QTEmbedded-4.8.2, and I am at a loss how to fix this.

Comment: No we have never solved it.  We got around it by writing a script that: 1) Makes a backup copy of the settings file at boot time if one does not exist.  2) Copies the backup settings file back if the existing settings file is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the same problem calling 'sync' linux command after the 'sync' function of QSettings.

Comment: always give your idea or trial in comments.

Comment: We have noticed that the sync function of QSettings forces to write keys and values to file.
The sync linux command actually stores the file on the file system.