# Replacement for sync() command

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, synchronization

I need to port one app on Windows. Originally that app was written on Linux and it uses Linux specific commands. I stacked at one place with sync(). Windows doesn't have such utility. The code looks like

```
QSettings *data
...
data->setValue("some_var", var);
data->sync();
sync();
```

That is a peace of C++ file. I don't know C++. It was written not by me. I use other languages. So how can I make it work on Windows or how can I rewrite that part?

Comment: Is it a function written as part of this project, or is it [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) (or something else, even)?

Comment: the second one. Synchronize data on disk with memory. There is no such function in the project code

Comment: I saw that answer but that requires administrative privileges to run. That is not an option. It is possible to have simple save function for windows. But have no idea how to write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to all the files you have open, I believe the equivalent of calling `sync()` on Linux is the same as going over all the file handles and flushing them on Windows, probably by using [FlushFileBuffers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT 1**

If you're using the C file interface (since you came from Linux), [fflush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) is your friend (you still need to have access to all open files.)

**EDIT 2**

I see there is a [_flushall()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xk9ehd.aspx) call you can use. Not sure about its similarity to Linux's `sync()` but they generylly seem to do the same thing. I'm also a little wary about using functions that start with underscore.

Comment: _flushall() looks very promising. But I got next error: error C2039: '_flushall' : is not a member of 'QSettings' The app is written in Qt. I should dig in that direction

Comment: This. Note that you'll need both `fflush` (or `_flushall`) **and** `FlushFileBuffers` as the former only flushes the cstdlib buffers to OS buffers, and the latter flushes the OS buffers to disk. Also note that you do not need administrative privilegues for that -- you need admin privilegues to flush a complete volume.

Comment: @poul The error code probably means that you haven't included the right header file for `_flushall()`. I believe you need to add `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: I did. my 'data' variable defined as QSettings *data

Comment: @poul I see. Well.... that's Qt stuff, which I know nothing about :) From the looks of it, the QSettings class indeed has a `sync()` member, so maybe you're missing `#include <QSettings>`? I'm looking here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html

Comment: @gnobal Probably you are right. I should leave data->setValue("some_var", var); data->sync(); and then call _flushall(); Then app compiles until next error.

Comment: @poul Great! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can ignore the system-specific `sync()` call. It's not needed, even on linux. `QSettings` does the right thing for you.

Comment: As question includes *"or how can I rewrite that part?"*, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: unfortunately there is a bug in Qt [which needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459010/875020) this workaround, it seems

Comment: @x29a Maybe there it was, in 2013. Absent a QTBUG link, I wouldn't worry much about it.